# getting comma in input type number in IE for cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

we have input type number in cshtml page . its working fine in chrome while form-validation.
But in Internet Explorer (IE), its accepting comma (,) in number field and saving it along with comma.
pls suggest.

**cshtml code:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.xxx, null, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @type = "number", @step = "0.01", @id = "xxx" })
```

**IE screenshot**: [image]

in IE, we can enter comma and its accepting it in value.

**Chrome screenshot**: [image]

Here, we are not allowed to enter comma.

in IE also i don't want comma. is there any constraint for this?

Comment: Probably helps to note which version of IE you're referring to - the number input type isn't supported in older versions.

Comment: Also, this seems to be a known "issue" - you'll find a reference to that on the MDN page for the number input, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use form validate.And use Input like the following(Without using @Html.TextBoxFor).I have a model,which has a property Id,and here is a demo:

View:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    <input name="Id" type="number" step="0.01" class = "form-control"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

js:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#myform").validate({
                rules: {

                    Id: {
                        required:true,

                        doubles: true

                    },


                },

                messages: {

                    Id: {

                        //doubles: "You can only enter numbers and dot"
                       

                    },

                }
            })
        })
        $.validator.addMethod("doubles", function (value, element, params) {
            var doubles = /^[0-9]*([.][0-9]{1,2})?$/;
            return this.optional(element) || (doubles.test(value));
        }, "You can only enter numbers and dot"); 
</script>
```

result:
[image]